# One WP install, I need to map a custom domain name to each category

Tags: categories, url-rewriting, domain-mapping

I've read other answers but they weren't satisfactory.

- [Multiple blogs, different domain names, one install to rule them all](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8450)
- [Multiple Domain Names - One WP Install (non-Multisite) - Default Each Domain name to Category Archive](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14837)

I did try the second option as it seemed perfect for my needs, however, what happens is that while a category is perfectly mapped to a domain, single articles are not and default to the original domain name.

I need to have each category keep its domain name when posts or sub-categories are clicked.

**i.e.:** 
`http://mywebsite.com/gastronomy/`

becomes `http://mywebsite-gastronomy.com`

**And:**
`http://mywebsite.com/2013/10/15/an-article`

becomes `http://mywebsite-{FIRST_CATEGORY_OF_THE_ARTICLE}.com/an-article`

Is this at all possible with URL trickery or plugins?

Comment: Just so as people know what you already tried and don't offer the same solution, which were those answers "not satisfactory"?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8450/multiple-blogs-different-domain-names-one-install-to-rule-them-all?rq=1, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14837/multiple-domain-names-one-wp-install-non-multisite-default-each-domain-nam?rq=1

Comment: I did try the second option as it seemed perfect for my needs, however, what happens is that while a category is perfectly mapped to a domain, single articles are not and default to the original domain name.

Comment: This question seems to be important, in that I have seen it asked a number of times, but there are no solutions provided. I believe I understand why: the posts are attached to the categories in the database with each page/post running on the same template as the rest of the posts/pages. I think this will take some clever .htaccess redirects. Maybe even brute force 301 redirects.